# php bulk rename images in directory

Tags: php, file-rename

I have a directory of about 2000 images. Image file names are structured like the following:

```
image1_r1.jpg
newimage2_r2.jpg
anotherimage3_r2.jpg etc etc
```

I have created the following to loop through and replace 'r1'. Once complete i will then manually change this to 'r2' and repeat for the rest.

```
if ($handle = opendir('/my-directory/')) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $newName = str_replace("r1","",$fileName);
        rename($fileName, $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

However when i run my script i get the following:

```
Warning: rename(sgr_dolly_duck_r1_item.jpg,sgr_dolly_duck_item.jpg): No such file or directory in /home/washington/public_html/rename.php on line 8
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: you are missing the dirname in the path to the file, so the function searches the file in your current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `/my-directory/` to the beginning of both `$fileName` and `$newName`. Or change the current working directory by calling `chdir('/my-directory/')` first.